# What's a good way to display text messages in JavaFX FXML?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I have been trying all day to create a JavaFX UI that will let me display short messages the way they do on a texting client.  I feel like the way to go would be with a GridPane, but I can't figure out how to set each box of the GridPane. Can someone please explain that or if you have a better solution I'd be glad to hear it.

Thanks!

Comment: _...display short messages the way they do on your phone._ I am not sure, what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried to debug

Comment: @pzaenger I'm basically trying to make a texting client.  Fixed the post, sorry that was a confusing way to say it.

Comment: @Aubin I can't seem to find anything online because I don't really know what to search for; nobody seems to have a similar question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a GridPane is perfectly possible, the important thing for a smartphone-message like style is to make sure you have `<ColumnConstraints halignment="LEFT" />` for the left column and "RIGHT" for the right column.

Labels can be used to display a message, with (for example)

- `-fx-padding: 10px;`
- `-fx-background-color` for different types of messages/different users
- `-fx-background-radius: 5px;`

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUFU5.png)

In Java, you can then simply add the Labels using [GridPane.add(Node, int, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#add-javafx.scene.Node-int-int-) with the first int parameter being 0 or 1 to determine the column and the second int being the number of the message, i.e. you can use a counter that is incremented by 1 for each message added.